# Halting a program at a debug point?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, nrepl, midje

I am using emacs for clojure development.

So after using: `C-u M-x cider-jack-in` (in my test file). Followed by `lein repl` followed by `M-x cider-connect` I get a strange, partially working repl at the root of my project where I have to provide the fully qualified path of every function complete with its namespace.

How can I provide cider a custom entry point (e.g. a test file)? How can I preload parts of the namespace, or halt execution at a specific point in the program?

Answer (score 2):

Preloading namespaces can be done with `C-c C-k` in the namespace.

You can place a debug point with `C-u C-M-x`. When you run code and hit a breakpoint you can follow the keybindings that appear to step in or over lines et cetera. You can use `C-c C-c` to remove the breakpoint.

See https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/debugging.md for more information on debugging.

Example from above link:
[image: An image of debugging commands]

Answer (score 1):

you can change your repl namespace by entering `(in-ns 'some.namespace)` in repl. Or otherwise cider allows you to switch to open file's namespace: open the file in emacs and execute `cider-repl-set-ns` (or `C-c M-n`).

To load the whole file into the repl use `cider-load-buffer` (C-c C-k), or `cider-load-file` (C-c C-l), and to load single s-expression use `cider-eval-last-sexp` (placing the cursor after sexp you want to exec and C-x C-e) or `cider-eval-sexp-at-point`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which appears to be about breakpoints.

Comment: To me it seems like it is the question about the repl and namespaces.